# remove special codes convert to normal (`%u021`, `%u0219`)

Tags: python

I have variables with this value :
`'Strada Constitu%u021Biei, Foc%u0219ani 620123, Romania'`

I need to remove this codes `%u021`, `%u0219` .. i tried all tutorial on internet, without success.

How i can convert this string to normal caracters ?

I need this output :

```
'Strada Constitutiei, Focsani 620123, Romania'
```

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach how i can convert my string in normal caracters ?

Comment: Where do these strings come from? Are the `%u` sequences encoded? If so, what encoding are they using? I could write an answer assuming they're not encoded, but if they are, the code would choke on certain inputs.

Comment: Related: [Python unicode codepoint to unicode character](/q/10715669/4518341), [What is the best way to remove accents (normalize) in a Python unicode string?](/q/517923/4518341), [Using f-strings with unicode escapes](/q/69380897/4518341)

Comment: @Lucian By "normal characters", you mean unaccented, right? i.e. `'%u021B'` -> `'ț'` -> `'t'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequences we need to replace in your example are actually `%u021B` and `%u0219`. Googling these, we find that they are "almost" unicode-escaped sequences. The only difference is, they do not start with a backslash, but with a percentage sign. If we had the proper unicode sequences, we could encode it (transform it to bytes) and then decode it again with the encoding "unicode-escape".

So, to transform your input, we replace all `%` signs first, and then apply this method:

```
def custom_decode(string):
    return (
       string
           .replace("%", "\\")  # "\\" here is double as it needs to be escaped
           .encode()
           .decode("unicode-escape")
    )

custom_decode("Strada Constitu%u021Biei, Foc%u0219ani 620123, Romania") 
# "Strada Constituției, Focșani 620123, Romania"
```

This limits potential input of our `custom_decode` method to strings which do not have a standalone `"%"` character, i.e. a % sign that is not indicating an escape sequence.

You might want to read about [encoding of strings in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding), and [in python in particular](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) to get a better understanding of what is going on here.

Comment: Careful, if the `%u` sequences are encoded, this won't work. With JSON for example: `s = '\N{grinning face}'; j = json.dumps(s).replace('\\', '%'); e = json.loads(j)` -> `'%ud83d%ude00'`, then `custom_decode(e)` -> `'\ud83d\ude00'`. This is using UTF-16.